# Elementary OS Juno - no sound after update

Tags: sound

after today's update my sound is lost. I have an Acer laptop UX430UNR.

I have today had a bigger update of the elementary os. Current kernel version is no 4.15.0-39. 
I have pulseaudio installed and under Sound settings the Built-in Analog Stereo device is recognised (as was before). The only problem is that I get no sound out of the speakers.
Please help...

Comment: A mixer showed up briefly on the task bar then disappeared. Gnome Alsa mixer didn't seem to run. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try with alsa mixer, if you want in graphic mode search in appcenter, it is called GNOME ALSA Mixer. verify that it is not muted.

cya.